# Using scrapy and selenium to crawl a static html but get nothing

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm new to scrapy/selenium. I want to crawl all paper titles from the website https://thewebconf.org/www2019/accepted-papers/. I think it is only a static html page because all content are shown in the source page when I "view page source". My code is below.

```
class Spider_WWW19(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "www19"
    start_urls = [
        'https://thewebconf.org/www2019/accepted-papers/'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        # add chrome driver to win10 PATH
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li//p[contains(@class, 'name')]"))
        )

        selenium_response_text = self.driver.page_source
        hxs = Selector(text=selenium_response_text)
        articles = hxs.xpath("//li//p[contains(@class, 'name')]/text()")
        for article in articles:
            yield {
                'title': article.text.strip(),
                'year': '2020',
                'conf': 'WWW',
                'conf_long': 'International World Wide Web Conference'
            }
```

But I have problems with it.

1. By using fetch from scrapy, the output html is blank.

`scrapy fetch https://thewebconf.org/www2019/accepted-papers/ > out.html`

2. By using scrapy without selenium, there is no output and the code is finished.
3. By using selenium, the generated browser does not navigate to the https://thewebconf.org/www2019/accepted-papers/ or anything. It was just closed.

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

find the solution: ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False